# Update Provider listeners based on condition

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have two Providers, where one is listening to the other one:

```dart
final counterStepProvider = Provider<AsyncValue<int>>(
        (ref) => ref.watch(counterProvider.state).whenData((double value) => value.floor()));

final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CounterState>((ref) => CounterState());

class CounterState extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<double>> {

CounterState(this.minCounter, this.maxCounter) : super(AsyncLoading()) {
    state = AsyncData(0);
  }

  set counter(double counter) {
    state = AsyncData(counter);
  }
}
```

The Problem is that `counterStepProvider` is always updating its listeners even if the state has the same value. Is there a way to update only if `value.floor != state`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure this would work with the way your providers are currently structured, but I recently came across select syntax that is available when using hooks. Maybe it will help you. https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#useprovider-hooks_riverpod-only

Comment: I have multiple listeners for that provider which are not widgets, so I would rather have a solution that would not involve filtering the state in the widget itself.

Comment: Fair enough. It would help if you provided your CounterState class.

Comment: I edited my code